# GRUB and installing a secondary SSD

Tags: grub2, ssd

I hope you can help pointing me in the right direction with this.

I currently have a dual-boot setup (I don't use Windows much, but i need it sometimes). I want to install an ssd drive in place of the dvd drive - and keep my current HDD.

When I proceed with the installation of Ubuntu on my new ssd, will GRUB recognise the operating systems on the hdd? Where will grub be installed?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: GRUB will install to /dev/sda unless you make it go elsewhere. Looking for answer to your other question.

Comment: Look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069 and scroll down to REPAIRING THE BOOT - so you can manually alter GRUB2 to add an item to point to sdb for Windows if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu will recognize your Windows install on the other drive and configure grub to boot it.  You can install grub to either drive ( there is a selector in the installer ), and it doesn't matter much as long as your bios is set to boot that drive.